# Getting an unknownHostException even aftr correcting the manifest file and data connection

Tags: android, android-camera

1. I am trying to make an app that takes a pic from camera on pressing a button and first displays it on a `SurfaceView` and then sends it to a `.php file` via internet. My code gives a "Error in http connection java.net.UnknownHostException: sibot.bugs3.com".
2. My MainActivity.java file is as follows

   ```
   public class MainActivity extends Activity {
       Button btn;
       ImageView img;
       @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

           btn=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
           img=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.sv);
           btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

               @Override
               public void onClick(View v) {
                   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                   CaptureImage(img);
               }
           });
       }

       private void CaptureImage( final ImageView iv_image) {

           int FrontCameraFound = getCameraID();
           if (FrontCameraFound != -1) {
               final Camera mCamera = Camera.open(FrontCameraFound);

               Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();

               mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
               mCamera.startPreview();

               Camera.PictureCallback mCall = new Camera.PictureCallback() {
                   @Override
                   public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
                       InputStream is;
                       Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);

                       // set bitmap tp image view just to check 
                       // if image capture proper, testing purpose
                       iv_image.setImageBitmap(bmp);

                       mCamera.stopPreview();
                       mCamera.release();
                     //  mCamera = null;
                     ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();                     
                       String bal;
                   try{  ByteArrayOutputStream bao = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

                       bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bao);

                       byte [] ba = bao.toByteArray();

                       bal=Base64.encodeBytes(ba);
                        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("image",bal));
                       }catch(Exception e){ Log.e("ERROR", "caught one "+ e.toString());}
                     try{

                         HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

                         HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://sibot.bugs3.com/pic.php");

                         httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                         HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

                         HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

                         is = entity.getContent();

                         }catch(Exception e){

                         Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());

                         }
                   }
               };
               mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mCall);
           }
       }

       private int getCameraID() {
           Camera.CameraInfo cameraInfo = new Camera.CameraInfo();

           for (int camIdx = 0; camIdx < Camera.getNumberOfCameras(); camIdx++) {
               Camera.getCameraInfo(camIdx, cameraInfo);
               // for capture image from back camera
               // If want to capture from front 
               // then change it to CAMERA_FACING_FRONT
               if (cameraInfo.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK) {
                   try {
                       return camIdx;
                   } catch (RuntimeException e) {

                   }
               }
           }
           return -1;
       }

       @Override
       public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
           // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
           getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
           return true;
       }

   }
   ```
3. My Manifest file is as follows

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       package="com.android.img2"
       android:versionCode="1"
       android:versionName="1.0" >

       <uses-sdk
           android:minSdkVersion="9"
           android:targetSdkVersion="9" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
           <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
           <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.INTERNET" />
           <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
           <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

       <application
           android:allowBackup="true"
           android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
           android:label="@string/app_name"
           android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
           <activity
               android:name="com.android.img2.MainActivity"
               android:label="@string/app_name" >
               <intent-filter>
                   <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                   <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
               </intent-filter>
           </activity>`enter code here`
           <activity android:name="com.android.img2.Base64" />
       </application>
   </manifest>
   ```

Even after including all the permissions and making sure the net on my cellphone is on, I wasn't able to solve the problem. Any help given would be appreciated.

Comment: You may want to make your exact question more explicit in the text. The information you've given is good, but may not be entirely clear what you're asking.

Comment: On the line of the code

    HttpPost httppost = new    HttpPost("http://sibot.bugs3.com/pic.php");

I am getting the "java.net.UnknownHostException: sibot.bugs3.com" error

Comment: After having added tags and seen in the Logcat i hereby concluded that the error comes on the line      HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

Comment: When I opened the .php page and sent da pic agen I got thi

    Service Temporarily Unavailable

The server closed the connection without sending any data.

The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems.

Due to heavy load on the server, connections may be temporarily blocked from locations that fetch an unusually high number of pages.

We apologize for the inconvenience